# Get 192bits cipher from 64bit blocksize in des

Tags: c#, encryption, des

I was wondering, is it possible to extend the cipher byte length when block size  64bits (8byte) in DES?

Its like this, When the input `Blocksize` is `<=64bits` the cypher size is `128bits` for sure because of the `PaddingMode.PKCS7` in DES. The below code is an example of what I'm saying.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            Console.WriteLine("Original String: ");
            string originalString = Console.ReadLine();
            string cryptedString = Encrypt(originalString);
            Console.WriteLine("Encrypt Result: " +cryptedString);
    }

    public static string Encrypt(string originalString)
    {

        const string AesIV = "!QAZ2WSX";
        const string AesKey = "5TGB&YHN";
        byte[] input_text = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalString);


        DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        des.BlockSize = 64;
        des.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesIV);
        des.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesKey);
        des.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        des.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;


        ICryptoTransform des_demo = des.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] encrypted = des_demo.TransformFinalBlock(input_text , 0, input_text.Length );
        string encrypt = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted );
        return encrypt;
    }
```

But I want to have cyphersize more than `128bits` (specially `192bits`) from same input `Blocksize` which is `<=64bits` from this code. How I can I do that? Is there any way to fix up the output cipher size to 24bytes?

Comment: this problem is solved. Please no more answers .

Comment: That's not for you to decide, Giliweed. The idea of this *forum* is that everybody can use and learn from the Q/A. Additional answers may be given at any time. And answers and questions may even be modified.

Comment: You are mistaken if you think that Unicode - or any other encoding for that matter - has anything to do with the output of a cipher. The input, output, key (and other possible parameters such as the IV) are always defined as bits. Usually they are of course implemented as octets (commonly referred to as bytes). The paper you were reading was incorrect in that sense; it referred to input/output as characters. It's one of their many mistakes. This is often due to the fact that the C/C++ (based) languages refers to a byte as `char`. Both Java and C# use a correct separation between the two though

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This problem can be solved very easily. Just change the `UTF8` to Unicode. Now, each input data characters will be `2byte` each instead of `1byte`. So, `8byte` (64bits) input will be `16byte` (128bits) and when `PKCS#7` is used in `16byte` data it becomes `24byte` (192bits). This is the way to get `192bit` cipher from `64bit` input.

Comment: This question *and* answer mistake bits/bytes with characters.